# Adding rows in table2 automatically on the basis of a specific column's input in table1

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:table1 and table2 in my mysql(phpmyadmin) database.

Table1 contains columns:id1(that auto-increments),desc1 and num.
Table2 contains columns:id2,desc2,id1(from table1) and desc1(from table1).

Firstly, when I add row in table1, same number of rows get added automatically in table2 as is the value provided in num.

Secondly, id2 should auto-increment for the same id1.As id1 changes, id2 should again begin from 1.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oneway to to this using trigger, something as

```
delimiter //
create trigger ins_table2 after insert on table1
for each row
begin
  declare t2_cnt_index int default 1;
  while t2_cnt_index <= new.num do  
    insert into Table2 (desc2,id1) values (new.desc2,new.id1);
    set t2_cnt_index := t2_cnt_index + 1; 
  end while ;
end ; //
delimiter ;
```

Comment: where should I add this in phpmyadmin

Comment: check this http://phpsblog.agustinvillalba.com/create-triggers-phpmyadmin/ you can add this on the PHPmyadin SQL command add section.